# How to change default snippets in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode Version:1.20.1
OS Version:windows 10 1709
Steps to Reproduce:

1.When I input `fun` and press tab,this code will show.

```
function name(params) {
}
```

2.I don't like this snippet.I want to change it, but I can not find a file about this snippet.

What should I do?

Comment: Because I dont need `name` and `params`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a default snippet but you can overwrite it.  So assuming javascript, try this in your javascript.json file:

```
"Function no name": {
    "prefix": "fun",
    "body": [
        "function () {",
        "",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Function no name or parameters"
},
```

Gear icon/User Snippets/choose your language.

Comment: Thank you for your ask,but I still want to change the default snippet.